# SSIS - data flow bug when running from a parent package

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I'm facing a very weird error with SSIS and can't seem to find the reason.

I have around 20 packages which run well when I run them manually one by one. however, when I run them through a parent package (master.dtsx) which calls each of those 20 packages individually one after another, I am getting all sorts of issues.

Main issue is this: I get all green checkmarks on the package itself:
[FULL SSIS SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SR2Z.png)

but the DATA FLOW is always wrong, see below:
[DATAFLOW SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Inzi.png)

And some of the packages simply fail without any error but they are all ok if I run them manually straight after.

I have tried to run the MASTER package through the sql agent job, but that gives me a completely different error:

```
Load_crmcci__Master:Error: The requested OLE DB provider MSOLEDBSQL is not registered. If the 64-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 32-bit mode. Error code: 0x00000000.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".
```

Excuse me if this sounds a dumb question but I have not been able to fix this issue for several days now on my own. so thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Are the child packages legacy DTS packages configured to run in 32 bit mode? Is the master package configured to run in 64 bit mode?

Comment: the value of FORCEDEXECUTIONVALUETYPE is set to "int32" for all of them  and FORCEEXECUTIONVALUE is "FALSE" for all... is that what you're asking?

Comment: Run64BitRuntime property on the project to set to TRUE from here: (right click the project, click properties, then go to the Debugging page to see the option)

Comment: I guess my issue was that the proper provider (DRIVER : MSOLEDBSQL) was not installed on the sql server. I've installed and ran the project again, waiting for results... will post the outcome here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my issue was that the proper provider (DRIVER : MSOLEDBSQL) was not installed on the sql server. I've installed and ran the project again, and it completed all properly.